# How do i add a dimension to a numpy array and copy the dimension from another numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pytorch

I have a numpy array with the shape (128, 8)
I want to add an extra dimension so it has the shape (128, 168, 8)
And add the content of a 168 dimension from another array that has the shape (128, 168, 8).
I can always permute the positions of the dimensions if I can somehow add it.
Is this possible somehow? I have seen the append and concatenation methods but to no luck.

Comment: `np.expand_dims(smaller_array, axis=1) + bigger_array` works fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
np.expand_dims(smaller_array, axis=1) + bigger_array
```

Is the correct solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can also do:

```
small[:,None,:]+big
```

Adding `None` to indexing creates a new dimension of size 1, and adding to another bigger array will broadcast the small's size=1 dimension to bigger arrays corresponding dimension size (here will be 168)